# Shell script randomly fails to execute file operations commands

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ubuntu-10.04, bioinformatics

I'm having a bit of trouble running this script.  Every now and then, it will fail to execute a `mv` command or `rm` command referenced below.  Then the next iteration will feel the full repercussions of that failure.  Why is this happening, and how do I control for it?  For reference, the syntax `phyml -i $f [parameters]` outputs the files `$f_phyml_tree.txt` and `$f_phyml_stats.txt` into the same directory as `$f`.  I want to get both these files out of that directory while saving the tree somewhere else.

```
ber="_phyml_tree.txt"
for f in ~/randseqs/aa/*.txt;
do
    echo $f
    fpath=`echo $f | cut -d'/' -f 6`
    if [ ! -f /home/mcb3421_10/phymlout/aa/$fpath$ber ] || [ ! -f /home/mcb3421_10/phymltimer/aa/$fpath ]; then
        phyml -i $f -d aa -b 0 -m Blosum62 > ~/blown.txt
        grep "Time used" < ~/blown.txt > ~/phymltimer/aa/$fpath
        mv /home/mcb3421_10/randseqs/aa/*$ber phymlout/aa
        if [ ! -f /home/mcb3421_10/phymlout/aa/$fpath$ber ]; then
            echo $f failed to write, check the logfile /home/mcb3421_10/phymllogs/aa/$fpath
        fi
        rm ~/randseqs/aa/*_stat*
        mv ~/blown.txt ~/phymllogs/aa/$fpath
    fi
done
for f in ~/randseqs/nuc/*.txt;
do
    echo $f
    fpath=`echo $f | cut -d'/' -f 6`
    if [ ! -f /home/mcb3421_10/phymlout/nuc/$fpath$ber ] || [ ! -f /home/mcb3421_10/phymltimer/nuc/$fpath ]; then
        phyml -i $f -d nt -b 0 -m HKY85 > ~/blown.txt
        grep "Time used" < ~/blown.txt > ~/phymltimer/nuc/$fpath
        mv /home/mcb3421_10/randseqs/nuc/*$ber phymlout/nuc
        if [ ! -f /home/mcb3421_10/phymlout/nuc/$fpath$ber ]; then
            echo $f failed to write, check the logfile /home/mcb3421_10/phymllogs/nuc/$fpath
        fi
        rm ~/randseqs/nuc/*_stat*
        mv ~/blown.txt ~/phymllogs/nuc/$fpath
    fi
done
```

Comment: First of all, add the `-e` to your shebang, for example `#!/bin/bash -e`, that way the script will exit after the first error, without causing further damage. When that happens read carefully the error messages, they will be your clue for fixing this.

Comment: agreed, and you might want to use shell trace tools `set -vx` or just `set -x` to see how variables are being expanded. You may find that some of your values have spaces in them. Best to dbl-quote all variables like `"$f" and "$ber"`. Good luck.

Comment: I made sure that all the filenames are space-free.  But what really puzzles me is that PhyML is analyzing the wrong file half the time.  When it is asked to analyze `randtree100.1.10.l1000.txt`, it instead analyzes `randtree100.5.4.l500.txt`.

Comment: as is, we're having to guess about what sort of inputs and the errors resulting. Can add some test cases (`true>file1.txt` for example), that will help us see the problem in action? Did you look at the output of `set -vx`? Good luck.

Comment: or are the files being processed the result of some relatively rapid and transient conditions in your system. I have seen "temporary" files show up in listings and then after all the other files before them have been processed, the temp file is missing by the time the script gets it in sequence for processing. Good luck.

Comment: I decided to work around the problem by copying the desired tree to a temporary directory and having PhyML work from there.  It seems to be working.